# How to get ResulSet multiple values into Java objects

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, resultset

I have 2 tables `Person (Person_id, name)` and `Address(Address_id, Person_idAd, addressName)` with relation of one-to-many.

With the following query I get

```java
String query = "SELECT Person_id, addressName from Person, Address where Person_id = Person_idAd"
        
PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
        
}
```

| Person_id | addressName |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | Address-1 |
| 1001 | Address-2 |
| 1002 | Address-1 |

I want to map this entries into Java objects.

```java
class Person {
    int id;
    ArrayList<String> addresses;
    // get and set...
}
```

Please let me know how it has to be done.
Thank you.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, add `ORDER BY Person_id` to the [SQL] query.
Also, your [SQL] query should use [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).

```sql
select P.PERSON_ID, A.ADDRESSNAME
  from PERSON P
  join ADDRESS A
    on P.PERSON_ID = A.PERSON_IDAD
 order by P.PERSON_ID
```

Whenever the `PERSON_ID` changes, create a new `Person` object and set the `id` member.
While the `PERSON_ID` remains the same, collect all the addresses into a `java.util.List`.
You probably also want another `java.util.List` to hold all the people.

```java
java.util.List<Person> people = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
int currentId = 0; // Assuming there is no such ID.
int id;
Person person = null;
java.util.List<String> addresses;
while (rs.next()) {
    id = rs.getInt(1);
    if (id != currentId) {
        if (person != null) {
            person.setAddresses(addresses);
            people.add(person);
        }
        person = new Person();
        person.setId(id);
        currentId = id;
        addresses = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    }
    addresses.add(rs.getString(2));
}
// Add the last person.
if (person != null) {
    person.setAddresses(addresses);
    people.add(person);
}
```

Of course, as an alternative, and if relevant, you could use a [Object Relational Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping) (ORM) tool like [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to build object similar like this within while

```
Person person = null;
List<String> addrList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs.next()) {
int id = rs.getXXX() //you will personid 

if(person==null) {
   person = new Person();
   person.setId(id);
   addrList.add(rs.getXXX);
   person.setAddresses(addrList);
} else if(id!=person.getId()) {
  person = new Person();
   person.setId(id);
   addrList.add(rs.getXXX);
   person.setAddresses(addrList);
}
}
```